# How underline text in MS Word with wavy red lines?

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I'm interested in MS Word document formatting. I'm developing addin on C# and want to know how draw wavy red line under some word programmatically?

Current code:

```
Word.Range targetWord;
targetWord.Font.Color = wdColor.wdColorRed;
```

where `targetWord` is a `Range` object

Comment: I managed to change font color of target words but this isn't what I actually need to do.

Comment: show your codes please

Comment: 'Word.Range targetWord;targetWord.Font.Color = wdColor.wdColorRed;' targetWord is a 'Range' object which I defined above. Here I showed only declaration because definition of targetWord is not the main part of my question. So, for given 'Range' object I would like to underline it with wavy red line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To underline the word, use:

```
targetWord.Underline = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnderline.wdUnderlineSingle;
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.range.underline(v=office.11).aspx

Answer (score 0):

using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

To color underline the word, you should use:
targetWord.Font.ColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdRed;